# How can I keep the referent from changing when the underlying data is modified?

Tags: perl

**Script1**

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my @results;
my @result1 = ('Chemisty', '87');
my @result2 = ('French', '80');

my $results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";

#
push @results, \@result1;
$results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";

#
push @results, \@result2;
$results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";
```

**Script2**

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my @results;
my @result1 = ('Chemisty', '87');

my $results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";

#
push @results, \@result1;
$results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";

@result1 = ('French', '80');

#
push @results, \@result1;
$results_len = scalar @results;
print "============   results [$results_len] ==========================\n";
print Dumper(\@results);
print "==========================**\n";
```

In script2... how should I clear result1 so I can reuse it again and get the output like in script1?

I tried undef, setting it to a blank... if I reset it again with "my result1" again it takes but that will flag a warning

Comment: "*get the output like in script1*" - Do you expect everyone here to copy/paste your code into a file and run it? Why not just post the output here so everyone knows what you're talking about?

Comment: Make each paragraph a function call? `addToResults(\@results, 'Chemisty', '87')`

Comment: Ideally, execute `my` twice (`my @row1 = ('Chemisty', '87'); my @row2 = ('French', '80'); my @results = ( \@row1, \@row2 );` or `while ( my @row = get() ) { push @results, \@row; }`), but you can also make a copy of the array if you have unusual code that reuses the same array (`push @results, [ @row ];`)

Answer (score 1):

`push @foo, \@bar` adds a reference to the named array `@bar` to the array `@foo`. If the contents of `@bar` are updated later, then it will affect the contents of `@foo`, too.

A workaround, when you anticipate that `@bar` will be updated, is to push a reference to a current *copy* of `@bar` onto `@foo`. This can be accomplished with the `[ @bar ]` syntax which creates a new array reference, initialized by `@bar`.

```
@bar = ( ... );
push @foo, [ @bar ];
@bar = ( ... ); # something else
push @foo, [ @bar ];
...
```